# Repetition seems to break my regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm writing a parser in java and narrowed a problem down to one of my regexs.  After toying with it and making the case simpler and simpler, I ended up with a test .txt file that its simply:

```
read a
```

and a Pattern that looks like:

```
... = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
```

"read" is parsed in a previous step and then my program throws an error because "a" is not recognized.  I am tokenizing the input and there is no whitespace. I had to trim the regex down to:

```
[a-z]
```

to get it to match.  If I add the '+' or anything else it fails.  Any insight?

EDIT: after looking at it again, [a-zA-Z] works, its the '+' that is breaking it.

Comment: There is no problem with your regex. The code which uses it/"throws an error" is where the problem is at.

Comment: So why would "match this exactly once" work and "match this once or more" fail?

Comment: Please post your actual java code, inlcuding where you get your input, tokenize it and match.

Comment: Print the string you are trying to match immediately before you actually invoke the regex. You will most likely see that the string is different from `"a"` (a wild guess is that the string is `" a"`).

Comment: Your regex is ok assuming you are using Scanner.next(Pattern p) method  to tokenize your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will match any text starting with letters, with an optional number of spaces, and then following with more letters. 
It will print both the whole match and the specific value after your space.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s*?(\\w+)");
String test = "read a";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("WHOLE MATCH: " + matcher.group());
    System.out.println("VALUE AFTER SPACE: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
WHOLE MATCH: read a
VALUE AFTER SPACE: a
```